# Get Items of ListView from Designer class within WinForms using Reflection in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, reflection

I am not sure if I am on right way to prove this concept. Here is the situation, I am trying to solve.

I have one WinForms project (VB.Net) and there is on form called `frmMain.vb`. It has designer class called `frmMain.Designer.vb`. I placed one `ListView` control on that form and set some static item collection to its `Items` property.

I am calling this WinForm assembly into one C# console application using `Reflection`. I wan to get list of items of that particulat `ListView`.

```
 Assembly AssemblyObject = Assembly.LoadFrom(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/WinForms.exe");
            if (AssemblyObject != null)
            {
                Type ExceptedType = AssemblyObject.GetTypes().ToList().Where(a => a.Name == "frmMain").FirstOrDefault();

                if (ExceptedType != null)
                {

                    MemberInfo members = ((TypeInfo)ExceptedType).DeclaredMembers.Where(x => x.Name == "ListView").FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Types don't contain data. You'd need to create the Form instance (`var formInstance = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(ExceptedType);`), then get the instance of the Control you're looking for (`formInstance.Controls.OfType<ListView>()` or `formInstance.Controls.Find("[ListViewName]", true)`) -- You didn't mention the .Net version in use, for both projects. It's quite important, tag your question accordingly.

Comment: You of course need to add a reference / dependency to `System.Windows.Forms` in your Console app. Or use UI Automation instead.